# specify random effects in lme4

Tags: lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I would like to ask for your help in specifying the random effects of a model I have been working on in `lme4`. I have data from a field survey. The objective of the study is to relate wing size (respond variable) with habitat (exploratory variable, categorical variable with 2 levels). We performed a paired design by sampling 50 individuals of 3 species in a simple habitat and the same 3 species (n=50 again) in a complex habitat in a region. We replicated that in 20 regions. I am not interested in the species specific effects. I am only interested across the community effects.
Is this model correct?

```
modela<-lmer(Wingsize~Habitat+(1|Region/Species)
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't your species be nested within habitat (which is in turn nested within region)?